# SMD ferrite beads to supress noise when driving mosfets

Tags: pwm, ferrite-bead

I design a simple circuit activates fan when processor heats up.
I started reading more, and I found a very interesting element a ferrite bead in smd form. It has 0.3ohm resistance, Imax 150mA and Impedance 120ohm (at 100 MHz).

I read that, this can be used as a gate drive resistor series with a lower value resistor to drive mosfets and this method reduces parasitic noise.

[image]

**Is it a good idea to use ferrite bead in this circuit?**

I don't have oscilloscope.
FAN: Sunon MF50100V1-1000U-A99, DC 5V, Imax 180mA, Vapo-Bearing™ technology

Comment: Why? What problem are you trying to solve? How’s the circuit performing with a standard 1-10 ohm resistor on the gate and no ferrite bead?

Comment: Ya, its good especially if you drive high speed, but you must know what you do. The combination with input Cgs likes to oscilate.

Comment: By all means leave space on the PCB and jumper if not needed. But ferrites without measurement tends to not be a good idea since they can make things worse. But your schematic has problems. If you don't PWM at high frequency, none of the gate resistor/ferrite stuff is required anyways.Bit if you are actually planning to PWM it at 30kHz like your schematic says your fan isn't oging to run properly. Your fan isn't just a motor. It is a brushless motor with an internal motor controller. You would be PWMing the power supply to the motor controller repeatedly turning it on and off. Won't work.

Comment: You are right! I did not take into account that it is a brushless motor.  Is there a way I can smooth the PWM coming out of the MOSFET into the fan motor?